# ¿Por qué GitHub no permite buscar archivos en repositorios forkeados?

Tags: github, buscador, licencias, git-fork

Vi que en *GitHub* se pueden hacer *forks* de los repositorios y además, se puede la lista de todas las bifurcaciones que hace la gente. Estaba mirando las de *MonoDevelop*, y cuando voy a buscar archivos, veo que aparece un mensaje diciendo que no se puede.

> Sorry, forked repositories are not currently searchable. You could try searching the parent repository.

En español sería:

> Lo sentimos, los repositorios bifurcados no se pueden buscar actualmente. Puedes intentar buscar en el repositorio principal.

¿Cuál es el motivo por el que no se pueden buscar archivos? ¿Es que no quieren o todavía no implementaron esa característica?

Esto me hace preguntarme otra cosa. ¿Está permitido hacer un clone de *MonoDevelop* y subirlo a un repositorio nuevo de mi GitHub sin que sea un fork directo? Además, ¿Se pueden hacerle modificaciones? De esta manera se podrían buscar archivos en el repositorio.

Si es posible... ¿Bajo qué condiciones? Teniendo en cuenta que es un proyecto de *Microsoft*. ¿Se le puede remover la licencia o dejo la licencia como está? ¿o debería agregar una licencia propia?

Comment: En realidad un fork es lo mismo que un clon privado, al menos en lo que respecta a `git`. La única diferencia es GitHub "toma nota" de que el clon en realidad proviene de otro, lo que le permite relacionarlos, entre otras cosas para cuando quieras hacer un _pull request_ (o sea, notificar al creador del repositorio original de un cambio que has hecho en tu fork, por si quiere aceptarlo y añadirlo al suyo). Al margen de la cuestión técnica, las condiciones de qué puedes y qué no puedes hacer sobre el fork (o clon) lo dicta la licencia. No deberías hacer nada que la licencia no te permita...

Comment: ... y mucho menos cambiarla por otra licencia propia

Comment: En cuanto a por qué no se puede buscar en el fork, supongo que es una decisión deliberada, para no sobrecargar sus bases de datos indexadas (que son las que permiten las búsquedas) innecesariamente, pues se pueden hacer búsquedas de todas formas en el original. [Aqui explican](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-in-forks/) que el fork se podrá buscar cuando consiga más estrellas que el original

Comment: @abulafia Creo que estaría bien que lo pongas como respuesta. Veo que tenía la licencia GPL y en 2009 cambió a LGPL. ¿Si se mezclan versiones que tienen diferentes licencias cuál es la licencia que se mantiene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respecto a los fork vs clone**. Desde el punto de vista de Git, no existen los *fork*. Un fork no es más que una copia de un repositorio con el que comparte una serie de *commits*, pero en el que a partir de un punto sus historias divergen. Es decir, un "clon" que hayas hecho de otro repositorio y en el que hayas hecho algún *commit*.

El concepto de "fork" para Git es abstracto, no se materializa de ninguna forma en el repositorio. Quien sí lo materializa es GitHub (o Bitbucket, o Gitlab, o el almacén de repositorios que uses). Cuando en GitHub haces un "fork" básicamente lo que hace es un clon del repositorio original en tu cuenta, y almacena (fuera de los repositorios) información de la relación entre ellos. Eso le permite a GitHub por ejemplo notificarte cuando el original tiene cambios, mostrar gráficas de la "red del proyecto" (que está formada por aquellos repositorios que han sido forks de ese), etc. Si lo clonas y lo subes, aunque para Git es lo mismo, para GitHub no, pues pierde esas relaciones entre repositorios.

Más importante aún, al hacer *fork*, ya que GitHub "sabe" que tu repositorio es copia de otro, te permite fácilmente hacer *pull requests*, que es la posibilidad de solicitar al autor del repositorio original que incorpore al mismo cambios que hayas hecho en tu copia. Al estar esos repositorios "conectados" a ojos de GitHub, le resulta muy fácil gestionar estas operaciones de modo que tanto para quien propone el pull como para quien lo acepta sea tan simple como hacer click en un botón.

**Respecto a por qué no se puede buscar en el fork**, supongo que es una decisión deliberada. Cuando haces una búsqueda en el código de un repositorio, realmente la búsqueda no se realiza en ese momento examinando los archivos del repositorio. Eso sería muy costoso. En cambio, el repositorio es analizado e indexado por los servidores de GitHub cuando hay cambios en él, y una base de datos contiene esos índices para posibilitar búsquedas rápidas.

Se ve que en GitHub han decidido que esa indexación no les merece la pena en un repositorio que sea *fork* de otro, ya que la búsqueda siempre puede hacerse de todas formas en el repositorio original. No obstante [aqui](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-in-forks/) mencionan que si el fork supera en popularidad (estrellas) al original, entonces comenzarán a indexarlo con lo que las búsquedas de código serían posibles.

En cualquier caso, para buscar código en un repositorio puedes hacerlo localmente en la máquina donde lo hayas clonado, con herramientas como [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), la cual recomiendo vivamente (te proporciona versiones binarias para linux, windows y mac).

**Respecto a las licencias**, aunque técnicamente clonar un repositorio (o hacerle un fork) sea muy simple, eso no implica que el autor del repositorio original te esté autorizando a hacer cambios, o a hacerlos públicos. Tendrías que leer la licencia que acompaña al repositorio para saber qué te está permitido y bajo qué condiciones. No deberías nunca cambiar la licencia original (a menos que la propia licencia te dé permiso).

No soy experto en licencias y no sé responderte a la pregunta que me haces en un comentario, acerca de qué licencia se aplica si mezclas versiones con diferentes licencias. Entiendo que la última, pero realmente no lo sé.